# Best practice for identifying a type of input text 

Tags: jquery, html, frontend

I have a type of input text that has to trigger a function on 'keydown'. In order to identify this type of input I used an Id #autocomplete. So

```
$('#autocomplete').keydown(function(){
   //function autocomplete
});
```

The problem is that I have this input twice in the same page, so jquery searches for the first id, and ignores the second one. (I am using an old jquery version, 1.3).

I solved it using **$("input#autocomplete")** instead. It works but is it a best practice? I guess Ids have to be unique. I could use *class* or *name* instead, but both have implications to other parts of code (*class* to the design, *name* to the server part the receives form parameters).

Which would be the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in doubt for `class` or `name` due their affects on `design` and `server`, you can always use attributes.

```
<input data-id="my-id"/>
```

and then select it like so

```
$("[data-id=my-id]")
```

custom attributes that has `data-` prefix are a standard in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

An `id` should be [**unique**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) across the entire `document` indeed. If you really can't make it unique, an alternative is your selector, or add a `class` to the `input` and then select it as `$(.class)`.

> The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element (which may
>   be verified by an SGML parser).